# Loop through dictionary and append them to a dataframe using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still quite new to Python and Pandas. I need some help with the code that i'm working with.

I have a dictionary called `df` which contains some files and their content in txt format. Key of this dictionary is the filename (date.txt), and value is the content of it. Here's what it looks like:

```
{'02_01_2020':                                                    0 
0  1  229017              Cust_1         CUR  ...
1  2  629324              Cust_2         CUR  ...
2  3  863300              Cust_3         CUR  ...
3  4  670338              Cust_4         CUR  ...
4  5  987039              Cust_5         CUR  ...
5  6  485912              Cust_6         CUR  ...,'03_01_2020':         0                                                  
0  1  122403              Cust_1         CUR  ...
1  2  779269              Cust_2         CUR  ...
2  3  728965              Cust_3         CUR  ...
3  4  527716              Cust_4         CUR  ...
4  5  796179              Cust_5         CUR  ...
5  6  027872              Cust_6         CUR  ...
6  7  449767              Cust_7         CUR  ...
7  8  598752              Cust_8         CUR  ...
8  9  180422              Cust_9         CUR  ..., .... goes until the last file ('31_01_2020')}
```

As you can see above, each file contains different data. File 02_01_2020.txt has 6 entries, file 03_01_2020.txt has 9 entries, and so on until the last file (31_01_2020.txt).

My goal here is to separate the necessary information into their own columns (customer name, currency, etc) with the filename inserted into a separate column called paid_date. I used `iterrows()` to loop through this dictionary file. Here's the code:

```
def data_process(df):

    #dataframe that i created outside this function
    global df_data_1

    for key,value in df.items():
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(value)
        df1['Paid_date'] = key.replace('_', '/')
        #df1.insert(1, 'Paid_date', key.replace('_','/')) - another attempt to insert the col
        
        for index,row in df1.iterrows(): 
            df_Item_Num = row.str.slice(start = 0, stop=2) # entry number
            df_DUMP_1 = row.str.slice(start = 0, stop=23) # not used
            df_NAME = row.str.slice(start = 23, stop=40) 
            df_CURRENCY = row.str.slice(start = 40, stop=54) 
            df_AMOUNT = row.str.slice(start = 54, stop=66)  
            df_DATE = row.str.slice(start = 68, stop=86) 
            df_DUMP_2 = row.str.slice(start = 87, stop=-1) # not used   
            df_ALL_ITEMS = pd.concat([df_Item_Num, df_NAME, df_CURRENCY, df_AMOUNT, df_DATE], ignore_index=True)
            df_data_1 = df_data_1.append(df_ALL_ITEMS, ignore_index=True)
                                
    return df_data_1
```

When i disabled the column creation code where the key is passed `df1['Paid_date'] = key.replace('_', '/')`, the result looks like this:

```
      0                  1               2             3                   4
0    1   Cust_1           CUR              Amount  Date_Time
1    2   Cust_2           CUR              Amount  Date_Time
2    3   Cust_3           CUR              Amount  Date_Time
3    4   Cust_4           CUR              Amount  Date_Time
4    5   Cust_5           CUR              Amount  Date_Time
..   ..                ...             ...           ...                 ...
185  10   Cust_6          CUR              Amount   Date_Time
186  11   Cust_7          CUR              Amount   Date_Time
187  12   Cust_8          CUR              Amount   Date_Time
188  13   Cust_9          CUR              Amount   Date_Time
189  14   Cust_10         CUR              Amount   Date_Time
```

Which is exactly what i need, only the paid_date column is not included (I need the filename to be stored in each row that corresponds to that particular file. e.g. 02_01_2020 would be printed 6 times to 6 rows, 03_01_2020 to 9 rows, etc). However, when i enabled the column creation code, it ended up like this:

```
      0   1                  2 3   ...             6 7                    8 9 
0    1   02  Cust_1                ...    Amount            Date_Time   
1    2   02  Cust_2                ...    Amount            Date_Time   
2    3   02  Cust_3                ...    Amount            Date_Time   
3    4   02  Cust_4                ...    Amount            Date_Time   
4    5   02  Cust_5                ...    Amount            Date_Time   
..   ..  ..                ... ..  ...           ... ..                 ... ..
185  10  31   Cust_6               ...    Amount            Date_Time   
186  11  31   Cust_7               ...    Amount            Date_Time   
187  12  31   Cust_8               ...    Amount            Date_Time   
188  13  31   Cust_9               ...    Amount            Date_Time   
189  14  31   Cust_10              ...    Amount            Date_Time
```

I have a couple of new empty columns and apparently the key (filename) is not fully inserted (only the date is somehow stored into the new column, month and year are not included). What is the most efficient way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

**Edit 1**

The entries of each txt file that i'm working with looks something like this:

```
1              CUST_NAME_1         CURRENCY            AMOUNT  DATE_TIME  
2              CUST_NAME_2         CURRENCY            AMOUNT  DATE_TIME
3              CUST_NAME_3         CURRENCY            AMOUNT  DATE_TIME
4              CUST_NAME_4         CURRENCY            AMOUNT  DATE_TIME
5              CUST_NAME_5         CURRENCY            AMOUNT  DATE_TIME
```

Inside the txt file, there's a lot of white space that separates the information as you can see above. What my code does first is to loop through the directory within my computer that stores all the files there, and append them to two lists. Here's the code:

```
#SET UP EMPTY LISTS & Dictionary
filelist = []
filename = []
df = {}

def file_process(mydir):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                filelist.append(file)
                filename.append(file[0:10])
    return filelist, filename
```

The above code returns two lists.

1. filelist contains each txt file (02_01_2020.txt, 03_01_2020.txt, etc)
2. filename contains only the name of each file (02_01_2020, 03_01_2020, etc)

Then i wrote the following code to convert those two lists into a single dictionary (will avoid using df for dictionary name, thanks for the suggestion).

```
def dict_process(filelist, filename):
    for key in filename:
        for value in filelist:
            df[key] = pd.read_csv(value, sep="delimiter", skiprows = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], skipfooter=6, header=None)
            filelist.remove(value)
            break
    return df
```

And the code above returns back the dictionary that i've written previously where the filename is set as the key, and all the file content as its value.

What i did (or thought i did) within the `for index,row in df1.iterrows():` was to slice every single series that `iterrows()` returned and keep only the information that i want and concatenate them into an empty dataframe. Is this efficient? or is there another way?

Comment: "I have a dictionary called df" and then you present something that isn't a dictionary but it's wrapped inside `{}` (and `df` is a name that _should_ be reserved for actual dataframes to avoid confusion). It's clear you've put a lot of effort in (nice first post!) but I can't quite follow the format you're dealing with

Comment: Also, everything inside `for index,row in df1.iterrows():` is pointless; you just throw the results away and overwrite the variables on each loop. I suspect you're actually dealing with a _tab delimited_ file

Comment: @roganjosh Hi thanks for the reply and suggestion (will keep them in mind for future code). My idea is to get all the data from a file, move important info in their own columns (name, currency, etc), and then store the filename into its own column and print it according to its entries. When i printed `print(type(df))` it says <class 'dict'>. It's dictionary isn't it? Or maybe it's a different? I'm still quite new to python and its data structures :D

Comment: It _could_ be a dictionary, but what you posted isn't valid syntax. I assume it's one big string literal, but you'd need quotation marks for that

Comment: Anyway, if it is tab delimited, then I think your attempts at slicing the strings are grossly inefficient; you can specify separators to read CSV data (which, potentially, this is)

Comment: @roganjosh i've edited the question. Any idea how to make it more efficient? thanks a lot for your input, appreciate it